# How to change the value of following button using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons like this:

```
 <button class="next_prev" onclick="" id="first_button" disabled>{{ pages.first }}</button>
<button class="next_prev" onclick="" id="last_button" disabled>{{ pages.last }}</button>
```

They show the first and last button as the page number. i.e 1 or 5. The button has always value. I want to replace their value as: `|<` for first and `>|` for last. How can I do that?

Comment: `$('button#first_button').val('|<');` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#first_button").text('|&lt;');
$("#last_button").text('&gt;|');
```

Comment: There are same four buttons in my same html document with the same id but it's working only with the two of them. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HTML ASCII` code as below and use `.html()` to add this as HTML,

```
$("#first_button").html('&#124; &lt;');
$("#last_button").html('&gt; &#124;');
```

`&#124;` is for `|`

`&lt;` is for `<`

`&gt;` is for `>`

For complete list <kbd>[**`Read`**](http://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('#first_button').html('new_name1');
$('#last_button').html('new_name2');
```

Comment: So that changes innerhtml for button? @Amrendra